# Getting Error while restoring Openerp database

Tags: mysql, postgresql, odoo

I was migrating my openerp database from one server to another. And while restoring database on another server I am getting this error

```
ALTER TABLE
ERROR:  insert or update on table "stock_move" violates foreign key constraint "stock_move_product_id_fkey"
DETAIL:  Key (product_id)=(2466) is not present in table "product_product".
ALTER TABLE
```

Please Suggest !!

Answer (score 2):

Error itself suggest that you don't have **Product_id = 2466** in the **product_product** table which is foreign key in **stock_move**. so you first need to **insert product with id = 2466 in product_product**